# How to get total number of db-hits from Cypher query within a Java code?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to get total number of db-hits from my Cypher query. For some reason I always get 0 when calling this:

```
String query = "PROFILE MATCH (a)-[r]-(b)-[p]-(c)-[q]-(a) RETURN a,b,c";
Result result = database.execute(query);
while (result.hasNext()) {
    result.next();
}
System.out.println(result.getExecutionPlanDescription().getProfilerStatistics().getDbHits());
```

The database seems to be ok. Is there something wrong about the way of reaching such value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ExecutionPlanDescription`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/ExecutionPlanDescription.html) is a tree like structure. Most likely the top element does not directly hit the database by itself, e.g. a projection.

So you need to write a recursive function using `ExecutionPlanDescription.getChildren()` to drill to the individual parts of the query plan. E.g. if one of the children (or sub*-children) is a plan of type `Expand` you can use `plan.getProfilerStatistics().getDbHits()`.

Comment: That was it! I wrote such recursive function and it gave me what I wanted. Thanks so much for your reply!